# Python staticmethod decorator with inheritance

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, decorator, static-methods

My case:

```
class BaseClass:

    @staticmethod
    def dummy_decorator(fnc):
        def wrapper():
            print('Im so dummy')
        return wrapper


class InheritedClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def anymethod(self):
        print('hello world')
```

When I look at `dir()`, I see my staticmethod

```
>>> c = InheritedClass()
>>> dir(c)
['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', 'anymethod', 'dummy_decorator']
```

Also, I can use my dummy operator as simple staticmethod inside new class. 
But when I try to use it as decorator -- I get error

```
class InheritedClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @dummy_decorator
    def anymethod(self):
        print('hello world')

>>> NameError: name 'dummy_decorator' is not defined
```

Why it works so? 
I know, that if I change `@dummy_decorator` to `@BaseClass.dummy_decorator` -- everything will work, but why I can't use decorator without ref to parent class?

Comment: You're trying to call the function `dummy_decorator`. There's no such function defined. `BaseClass.dummy_decorator` is the only thing of that name that exists.

Comment: why I see `dummy_decorator` in `dir(c)` then? And I can use it without @, just as function

Comment: Because *once the class is defined*, it inherits everything from its parent class. But at the point you're trying to call it, the class isn't done being defined yet and hasn't inherited anything yet. Anything directly inside a `class` block is basically just plain Python code; `dummy_decorator()` wouldn't work outside a `class` block either for the same reason.

Comment: Could you please comment this `the class isn't done being defined yet and hasn't inherited anything yet`. I can't figure out what do you mean

Comment: When you `dir(c)` you see methods and attributes of the instance, that means the class was already created before that. As the class is derived from BaseClass it has inherited the method. After this definition if write your second code you can put `@InheritedClass.dummy_decorator` as well

Comment: Because you don't have access to inherited names in the class scope, you have to use `BaseClass.dummy_decorator` Note, the fact that it's a staticmethod is not really relevant. This would work with any normal class attribute, say, `foo = "bar"` The key issue here is scope in a class block

Answer (score 0):

The reason why is baecause it is a static method, it belongs to the class as you have figured out when you put `@BaseClass.dummy_decorator` and it worked.

It is an attribute of the class so you can't just refer to it by `dummy_decorator` unless you move it out of the class or save it into the global namespace

Answer (score 0):

To understand this properly, you need to understand how `class` definitions work. In a nutshell, everything inside a `class` block is executed just like regular Python code. Every *name* that has been created inside that `class` block (e.g. `def` or variable assignments) are then wrapped up at the end of the `class` block and become attributes of the new class object. It goes something like:

```
# START CAPTURE
def __init__(self):
    pass

foo = 'bar'
# END CAPTURE

InheritedClass = # OBJECT WITH ATTRIBUTES "CAPTURED" ABOVE AND ADDITIONAL MAGIC
```

So, any code within the `class` block is just regular Python code. It hasn't "inherited" anything yet. That's the "additional magic" applied to the resulting class object at the end of the `class` block. And since there's no global "`dummy_decorator`" name defined, you can't call it by that name. It exists as "`BaseClass.dummy_decoator`", same as it would outside any `class` block.